# Robot Framework: Parameterized GUI elements

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, katalon-studio

in Katalon is a very nice way to parameterize the selectors for GUI elements, so that you can easily select very similar elements with the help arguments. I want to do something similar like that in Robot Framework.

EDIT: Better example, that is more easy to understand:

We have several GUI elements we have to interact with when testing. As the elements' selectors are very similar, we want to parameterize specific parts of it. In this case, we want to parametrize the $(selector) part of the selector:

```
*** Variables ***
$(overview.element}    //div[contains(@class, $(selector)')]
```

We want to be able to do that, so that we can avoid something like that

```
*** Variables ***
$(overview.home}    //div[contains(@class, home')]
$(overview.settings}    //div[contains(@class, settings')]
$(overview.overview}    //div[contains(@class, overview')]
```

We want to give that parameter within the test cases. Means: We can specify which element we want to select. Something like that:

```
    [Arguments]   ${selector}
Click    $(overview.element)(${selector})
```

Is that possible? And if yes: How?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Can you take away the downvote please? I edited it much much better and I want people to read it (I edited it almost immediatly after I saw the mess I wrote)

Comment: Why did you tag this Python? It seems like that has nothing to do with what you are trying to do. You're using Katalon, right?

Comment: I useD katalon to do this task before. Right now I'm using Robot Framework (a testing framework written in Python).

Comment: Can you give us a small code sample of what you have in Python?

Comment: I don't have anything written in Python. Well I just delete this tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in keyword [Replace variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Replace%20Variables) to perform the substitution before using the locator. For this to work you'll have to escape the variable reference when defining `${overview.element}`

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
${overview.element}    //div[contains(@class, \${selector}')]

*** Keywords ***
Example keyword
    [Arguments]  ${selector}
    ${locator}=  Replace variables  ${overview.element}
    log  locator is ${locator}

*** Test cases ***
Example
    example keyword  settings
```

When you run the above, the log should show this:

[image]